# ES6 typescript implementing method with nested typed return object not working. Property or signature expected

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, interface

What rule of inheritance or syntax oversight am I missing?

This appears like it should work for me, however, I am getting error saying, "Property or signature expected."

```
export interface RestCriteria {
    page: number,
    pageSize: number
}

export interface ResponseMetaData {
    page: number,
    pageSize: number,
    totalRecords: number
}

export interface QueryResponse {
    metaData: ResponseMetaData,
    records: []
}

export interface RestService {

    query: (criteria: RestCriteria) => QueryResponse,

}

class Rest implements RestService
{
    query: (criteria: RestCriteria)  => { //why is this not valid??
        return {
            metaData: {
                page: 1,
                pageSize: 1,
                totalRecords: 1
            },
            records: []
        }
    };
}

export default Rest;
```

Comment: Because that's object literal syntax, not `class` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

there is actually another error which is that you were returning a {} and not a QueryResponse(see my solution below). Regarding the error you mentioned for the property or signature requested it can be fixed by adding a ! after query.

Replace your Rest Class with the following

```
class Rest implements RestService
{
    query!: (criteria: RestCriteria) => {
        metaData: {
            page: 1,
            pageSize: 1,
            totalRecords: 1
        },
        records: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the syntax

```
class Foo {
  prop: X;
}
```

`X` is the annotated *type* of the `prop` property; it is not a *value* of the `prop` property.  If you want to initialize a property, you should use the syntax

```
class Foo {
  prop = Y;
}
```

where `Y` is now the initial *value* of the property.  You can both annotate and initialize if you want, like

```
class Foo {
  prop: X = Y;
}
```

Anyway, in your code, you've got `query` as your property, and it looks like you are trying to initialize it... but you're using the annotation syntax.  Thus the compiler tries to interpret `(criteria: RestCriteria) => { return { ...` as a *type*, and gets very unhappy when it sees `return`.  One possible solution here is to change `:` to `=`, like this:

```
class Rest implements RestService {
    query = (criteria: RestCriteria): QueryResponse => {
        return {
            metaData: {
                page: 1,
                pageSize: 1,
                totalRecords: 1
            },
            records: []
        }
    };
}
```

Note that if you *only* change `:` to `=` you'll get another error because of a [longstanding design limitation in TypeScript, microsoft/TypeScript#3667,](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3667) in which the compiler does not look at what a class `implements` or `extends` to contextually type its properties.  The way around this is with more annotation, so that's why I have the arrow function annotate both the input and output type (that is, I changed it from `(param: InputType) => valueOfOutputType` to `(param: InputType): OutputType => valueOfOutputType`).

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJWAGcYBhKBVCzOAbwFgAoOFuMTAc2AC44kBXALYAjNABomrNp2ABlBAC8efIaKhMAvkyahIsRCjRZcBYpCRFgAWWAxMAEUx26k1uy68BI8a5bu5ispeahLMrDAQdgA2hNjQACZEnqpomtqMutDwyFTGeACK-GgAnoRE5pYuYSyCtg5OmLxlFdZ1jnahUlDAcVCJvADaALppjDrgWQa5OHhlMLJoAG4IJgzVcACORVDFvAAU2BRUCI2mJOSUaCcAlHAAvAB8cIUlzRAWwKFaY4zYUZhEIhnbKCMBRYC1FBAuYLKDLVa+TbbYr3OAHI5XU5zC7HTDXXgvHZvD73J5rKRdWz8KBIKoU+lwWp2dqnckM9n+XgARk67IZ-nkSm5vL5FIi0ViCSScC5iPZGhFfO6vX6cGGctY3ykGgA3KMgA)